# could not set 'core.repositoryformatversion' to '0'

Tags: git, github

I am trying to initialize a new git repo.  When I execute `git init` in the target directory I receive the following:

```
error: chmod on /r/test_file_path/.git/config.lock failed: Invalid argument
fatal: could not set 'core.repositoryformatversion' to '0'
```

I've never run into this issue before and the solutions i've looked up appear to be odd and disjointed.  I've initialized other git repos in this directory before and have never had a problem.  Any thoughts what this could be?

Comment: What OS are you using and what file system is that repository on?

Comment: @bk2204 Using Windows 7 Pro and the file system is NTFS

Answer (score 1):

Are the files synced/on your device?

Got the same error when running git in a folder containing "online" files.

After starting OneDrive git worked correctly again.

Answer (score 0):

There was a 2.27 regression, now fixed.
But any new extensions in a v0 repository would still be silently honored, which is not quite right.
Instead, complain and die loudly with Git 2.29 (Q4 2020).

See [commit ec91ffc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ec91ffca0455e1a8a0525fb2a10814447d80c456) (16 Jul 2020) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c28a2d0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c28a2d0c12cbd897adf48c52b4d6275a4b84bb78), 30 Jul 2020)</sup>

> ### [`verify_repository_format()`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ec91ffca0455e1a8a0525fb2a10814447d80c456): complain about new extensions in v0 repo
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> We made the mistake in the past of respecting `extensions.*` even when the repository format version was set to 0.
> This is bad because forgetting to bump the repository version means that older versions of Git (which do not know about our extensions) won't complain.
> I.e., it's not a problem in itself, but it means your repository is in a state which does not give you the protection you think you're getting from older versions.
>
> For compatibility reasons, we are stuck with that decision for existing extensions.
> However, we'd prefer not to extend the damage further. We can do that by catching any newly-added extensions and complaining about the repository format.
>
> Note that this is a pretty heavy hammer: we'll refuse to work with the repository at all.
> A lesser option would be to ignore (possibly with a warning) any new extensions. But because of the way the extensions are handled, that puts the burden on each new extension that is added to remember to "undo" itself (because they are handled before we know for sure whether we are in a v1 repo or not, since we don't insist on a particular ordering of config entries).
>
> So one option would be to rewrite that handling to record any new extensions (and their values) during the config parse, and then only after proceed to handle new ones only if we're in a v1 repository.
> But I'm not sure if it's worth the trouble:
>
> - ignoring extensions is likely to end up with broken results anyway (e.g., ignoring a proposed `objectformat` extension means parsing any object data is likely to encounter errors)
> - this is a sign that whatever tool wrote the extension field is broken. We may be better off notifying immediately and forcefully so that such tools don't even appear to work accidentally.
>
> The only downside is that fixing the situation is a little tricky, because programs like "[`git config`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ec91ffca0455e1a8a0525fb2a10814447d80c456/Documentation/git-config.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config))</sup> won't want to work with the repository. But:
>
> ```
> git config --file=.git/config core.repositoryformatversion 1
> ```
>
> should still suffice.

Answer (score -3):

May be try fisrt SU or sudo git init.